# Is it possible to make 3d phase portraits?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a system of equations consisting of three equations. Is it possible for me to draw a 3d phase portrait on a mathematical software? If yes, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/plotting-a-set-of-trajectories-not-a-vector-field-in-3d

Answer (score 1):

You can plot a bunch of arrows or trajectories in 3 dimensions, but the result will generally look messy.  Or you can plot the "isoclines" $\dot{x}=0$, $\dot{y}=0$, $\dot{z}=0$, which will be surfaces.  Again, can be messy and hard to interpret.